# Using git diff with xargs -0, spaces in file names

Tags: bash, msysgit

What I'm attempting to do is extract a list of 'projects' which have changed since a given commit. For this I'm approximating a project to a folder containing a changed file.

The problem I'm having is getting this to work with files which have spaces in their names:

```
$ git diff --name-only TREEISH.. | xargs -n 1 dirname
```

I've looked at the `-0` option for `xargs`, and the `-z` option for `diff`, but this gives me:

```
$ git diff --name-only -z TREEISH.. | xargs -0 dirname
dirname: too many arguments
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
git diff --name-only -z TREEISH.. | while IFS= read -r n; do dirname "$n"; done
```

- IFS is the input field separator, needed to avoid trimming leading/trailing whitespace
- -r is needed to avoid backslash processing.
- The quotes around "$n" make it deal with spaces.

See [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) for more information.